# How do i place the particles from particles.js behind my content?

Tags: javascript, html, particles.js

I'm trying to put the particles animation from particles.js behind my div.

I've tried placing all my content inside the #particles-js div and changing the z-index for the content and the #particles-js.

This is how the HTML looks:

```
<div id="particles-js">
        <header>
            <h1>Vibe!</h1>
            <h2>Outwit your friends</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="main">
            <div class="container">
                <p>What should we call you?</p>
                <input class="input input-lg"type="text">
                <button class="btn btn-lg">Join</button>
                <button class="btn btn-lg">Create</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My CSS also features many `position: absolute` tags, could that be the reason?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j305exgy/

Comment: Your code doesn't have enough information to provide a solid answer. If you can provide a working example using jsbin or jsfiddle, it will be easy for contributors to help. 

But as you suspect, `position absolute` and `z-index` styles can create such problems. Try removing all the `position absolute` styles for all the parents and debug where the issue is.

Comment: @Jebin added my JSFiddle

Comment: In the fiddle, particles.json is not found. Please fix it first.

Comment: Check this. https://jsfiddle.net/7aLnpkoh/

Comment: @Jebin Thanks, got it :D

Answer (score 1):

You were missing the particle json file.

JS:

```
particlesJS("particles-js", {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 380,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#ffffff"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "circle",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "img/github.svg",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 0.5,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 3,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 40,
        "size_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": true,
      "distance": 150,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 0.4,
      "width": 1
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 6,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": false,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": true,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 140,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
});
```

CSS

```
#particles-js {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="particles-js"></div>
```

Working example: [jsfiddle.net/7aLnpkoh](http://jsfiddle.net/7aLnpkoh)

Answer (score 0):

You were missing z-index: -1;

```
#particles-js {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px;
     z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: You can use [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68841478/edit) to update your answer instead of posting additional explanation in comments.